# How to easily share code between iOS and Mac Catalyst in .net 6?

Tags: .net, xamarin, .net-6.0, csproj, visual-studio-mac

I'm in the process of upgrading a Xamarin Native solution to run on .net 6 using SDK style multi-targetted projects.

As I understand it, there are two ways of writing platform-dependent code:
a) Code inside the appropriate platform directory (e.g. "iOS" or "MacCatalyst") is always compiled conditionally for that platform.
b) Code can be explicitly conditionally compiled via e.g., `#if IOS`.

Neither of these seems ideal when there is a large body of code that is shared between two platforms. In (a) the code is duplicated and in (b) the code is strewn with `#if`s.

Is there a better way to share code between these two platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm considering creating a "Shared" folder under `Platforms/iOS`
and symlinking that folder to `Platforms/MacCatalyst/Shared`.

Still holding out for other answers, as well as comments on this one.

EDIT: I tried this on Visual Studio For Mac 2022. The symlinked folder at `Platforms/MacCatalyst/Shared` appears as a single file with a reddish title in Solution Explorer, i.e., its subtree isn't visible. However, the project complies fine for both iOS and Mac Catalyst. Since the shared code is accessible from its original location at `Platforms/iOS/Shared`, this looks like valid albeit somewhat unsupported strategy.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: Yes, had already confirmed that git does understand symlinks. Thanks though.

Comment: As mentioned above, git does support symlinks. And from what I've read Windows traditionally requires running in elevated privileges to create symlinks, but that can now be overridden by turning Developer Mode on.

Comment: I finally remembered why symlinks were a headache in VS 2015, for sharing code between projects: **VS didn't realize the linked copy "was the same file".** Implications: Every error was listed twice. Search listed each result twice. Editing one file is not seen in the copy until file save. Worse, a refactor is not seen until save - causing intellisense errors in the other projct, until save. Worst of all, its possible to have **both** copies open for editing **at the same time**, then (unknowingly) make different edits in the two copies. Second save wiped out first. See if any of these happen.

Answer (score 2):

[MSBuild Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2022) can be used to control build actions under different circumstances.

Given the default value `true` of `<EnableDefaultCompileItems>`, the easiest approach is to REMOVE a folder from targets that shouldn't have it.

The goal is to have (most) iOS code be included on both iOS and MacCatalyst; therefore exclude it from all other target frameworks.

Steps:

- Create a folder under the project root. E.g. `iosShared`.
- Place in that, the files (and subfolders) to include in both iOS and MacCatalyst builds.
- By default, those files would be included for all targets. Stop that by adding to `YourProject.csproj`:

```xml
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net6.0-ios' And
                          '$(TargetFramework)' != 'net6.0-maccatalyst'">
        <Compile Remove="iosShared\**\*" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but it seems promising. The only complexity I can think of is that the TFM's may need to be kept in sync with the TargetFrameWorks property. Sometimes a target framework needs to be qualified with an OS version tacked on at the end. How can we use a "does not contain" predicate instead of a "not equal to" predicate to make this more robust? Also, does "*.*" correctly remove files in subfolders?

Comment: subfolders - good question, probably needs a longer syntax; I only tested with files directly in folder. "does not contain" - there’s a `Trim` method that removes specified characters. You could remove digits and dots. Also see [MsBuild Conditional Constructs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditional-constructs?view=vs-2022) - I’ve never used, but looks very powerful. Even a regex example.

Comment: All files in a folder and its subfolders - `... iosShared\**\*.*`. Answer edited.

Comment: Hmm - in other contexts, such an expression can be simplified to `iosShared\**\*` without the trailing .* - i.e. the extension does not need its own wildcard. I wonder if the same works here.

Comment: Ahh, I looked more closely at [doc examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-select-the-files-to-build?view=vs-2022). Looks like that works too. Probably `*.*` is holdover from earlier, dumber, command environment.

Answer (score 0):

Late joining the discussion. Here's the solution I came up with. The following snippet intelligently copies over those .cs files that have changed in iOS and makes sure to delete any .cs files under MacCatalyst that no longer have an equivalent sibling file under iOS.

Note that if you are to use this in your CI pipeline you will have to invoke the target 'CloneIOSSourceCodeToMacCatalyst_Impl' explicitly and separately before launching the build on the .csproj like so:

```
<!-- its vital to call this target explicitly before compilation kicks in -->
<Message Importance="High" Text="** [Builder] Copying iOS *.cs -> MacCatalyst"/>
<MSBuild Projects="path/to/your/project.csproj" Targets="CloneIOSSourceCodeToMacCatalyst_Impl"/>
        
<!-- COMPILE  -->
<MSBuild Projects="path/to/your/project.csproj" Targets="Build"/>
```

And snippet itself:

```xml
    <!-- this is meant to be an automation automatically invoked by the IDE itself to make our lives a bit easier -->
    <Target Condition=" $([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst' "
            Name="CloneIOSSourceCodeToMacCatalyst"
            BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
        <CallTarget Targets="CloneIOSSourceCodeToMacCatalyst_Impl"/>
    </Target>

    <!-- we made this a separate target without conditions so that it will be directly invocable by our build script -->
    <Target Name="CloneIOSSourceCodeToMacCatalyst_Impl">
        <Message Importance="High" Text="**** [CloneIOSSourceCodeToMacCatalyst_Impl] Copying iOS *.cs -> MacCatalyst"/>

        <!-- intelligently copy over only the files that changed from ios -->
        <ItemGroup>
            <iOSFiles Include="Platforms\iOS\**\*.*"/>
        </ItemGroup>

        <Copy SourceFiles="@(iOSFiles)"
              DestinationFolder="Platforms\MacCatalyst\%(RecursiveDir)"
              SkipUnchangedFiles="true"/>
        
        <!-- and now delete all those files under mac-catalyst that no longer have an equivalent sibling file under ios -->
        <ItemGroup>
            <MacCatalystSourceFiles Include="$([System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles('Platforms\MacCatalyst', '*.cs', SearchOption.AllDirectories))" />

            <MacCatalystSourceFiles>
                <RespectiveIosFilePath>$([System.String]::Copy('%(Identity)').Replace('MacCatalyst', 'iOS'))</RespectiveIosFilePath>
            </MacCatalystSourceFiles>

            <RespectiveIosFiles Include="@(MacCatalystSourceFiles->'%(RespectiveIosFilePath)')" />
            <RespectiveIosFilesThatDontExist Include="@(RespectiveIosFiles)" Condition=" !Exists(%(RespectiveIosFiles.Identity)) " />

            <RespectiveIosFilesThatDontExist>
                <RespectiveMacCatalystFilePath>$([System.String]::Copy('%(Identity)').Replace('iOS', 'MacCatalyst'))</RespectiveMacCatalystFilePath>
            </RespectiveIosFilesThatDontExist>

            <MacCatalystStrayFilesToDelete Include="@(RespectiveIosFilesThatDontExist->'%(RespectiveMacCatalystFilePath)')" />
        </ItemGroup>

        <Delete Files="@(MacCatalystStrayFilesToDelete)" />

        <Touch Files="Platforms\MacCatalyst\_DONT_EDIT_ANY_FILES_IN_HERE__ITS_POINTLESS_" AlwaysCreate="true" Condition=" !Exists('Platforms\MacCatalyst\_DONT_EDIT_ANY_FILES_IN_HERE__ITS_POINTLESS_') " />
    </Target>
```